# How can I calculate ${2133}^{5525}$ mod ${7387}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, calculator

I would like to calculate the modulus of a large number.
How can I do it? Is there an easy way to calculate it, without really using the calculator? How can I get these solutions?

1. ${2133}^{5525}\pmod{7387}$
2. ${0429}^{5525}\pmod{7387}$
3. ${1126}^{5525}\pmod{7387}$

I know that the solutions are:

1. $2431$
2. $2312$
3. $1528$

Comment: Maybe this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers

Comment: *Hint*: Note that $7387=83\times 89$..

Comment: They are all to the 5525 power which is $13*17*5^2$.  A strongly suspect the sadist who made this problem has something in mind about $\phi(7387)$ have something to to do with it.  Except $7387$ is $83*89$ (no, way in heck was I going to do that without a calculated.  Can use $CRT$ to for mod 83, 89.

Comment: Numbers are from [this exercise on RSA](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/387), where they use repeated squaring (i.e. it is not designed to be easy to do by hand).  Is the question really about how exponentiation by repeated squaring works?

Comment: I really do not know, my prof wants every step. I just calculate these modules with a calculator.

Comment: @MaL check my answer, is it sufficient giving an idea how to prove? or do you need more elaboration?

Comment: A very frequently used algorithm is repeated squarings: express the exponent as a binary number, set the answer as $n=1$ & $m=$ the number _being raised to the power_ ; and proceeding from right to left through the binary digits of the exponent - if it's 1, multiply $n$ by $m$; and if there are anymore digits left, do $m\to m^2$. _All_ calculations are done $\operatorname{mod}$ _whatever_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all, $7387$ is not a prime number, it is $83*89$. You need to calculate the answer module these primes. Then, by CRT, the answer will follow to the given number.
- You may need to use *Fermat Theorem* which says $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ if $\gcd(a,p) = 1$ to reduce these huge powers. For example, with the prime $83$, you may notice that $5525=62*88+69$. Now, $2133^{5525} \equiv (2133^{88})^{62} \times 2133^{69} \equiv 2133^{69} \pmod {89}$. Now, *$2133^{69}$still big for the calculator?*, we can use the following trick. It is called *repeated squaring*.

I will solve $2133^{69}$ using this method, the others you just follow it up. Now, $2133^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {89}$ and $9^2 \equiv -8 \pmod {89}$ and $(-8)^2 \equiv 64 \pmod {89}$. This way, we have calculated $2133^{2^{2^{2}}} = 2133^{16}$. Now, we can multiply this number $\pmod {89}$ 4 times to get $2133^{16+16+16+16} = 2133^{64}$. This yields $2133^{64} \equiv 4 \pmod {89}$. Further, we need to multiply it by $2133^5 = 2133^{4+1} \equiv -8*2133 \equiv 24 \pmod {89}$.

Answer (score 1):

$7387=(83)(89)$

Start by reducing exponentiation

$\begin{cases}
2133^{5525}\pmod{83}\equiv(2133\pmod{83})^{5525\pmod{82}}\equiv 58^{31}\pmod{83}\equiv 28\pmod{83}\\
2133^{5525}\pmod{89}\equiv(2133\pmod{89})^{5525\pmod{88}}\equiv 86^{69}\pmod{89}\equiv 24\pmod{89}
\end{cases}$

By Chinese remainder theorem then $2133^{5525}\pmod{7387}\equiv 2431\pmod{7387}$

For the intermediate calculations (of $24$ and $28$) there are still some calculation to do, exploit small congruences (for instance $86\equiv -3\pmod{89}$) and dichotomy on the exponent.

I let you do the other ones.

Comment: deserves  an upvote, although an explanation on how to find these huge powers would be preferable.

Comment: Mathematically sound, cryptographically vulnerable to glitching attacks.